# Is $a^n b^n$ context free even if we take strings instead of characters?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

Let a and b be 2 **strings** . Does the set {$a^nb^n$ , $n\geq0$} still form a context free language?

Intuitively, I feel that should be the case since in this case I'm just storing strings instead of characters in my stack for the Pushdown automata but I am not able to prove anything. Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: As stated in @HallaSurvivor 's answer, the closure under homomorphisms confirms your feeling. In the other direction, the language can even become simpler. If, for example, a=01 and b=0101, then the language is regular: $(010101)^+$. More general: the language is regular if a and b have the same primitive root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

As a hint, recall the [homomorphic image of a context free language is context free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Closure).

Can you see why your language is a homomorphic image of the context free language
$\{ x^ny^n \} \subseteq \{x,y\}^*$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^